# How do I insert a breakpoint into a read-only function in R where the source is not availalable

Tags: r

My goal is to be able to reasonably debug any R-based code, even code from libraries (from `install.packages`, by placing breakpoints or debug statements (i.e., `browser`) at any line. I haven't been able to figure out how to reliably edit the source of any library function yet (assuming it is not compiled, e.g., editing a S3 method). However, I put a breakpoint in my main function and then used the debugger to step into the code for the library of interest. In RStudio, the file says "Debug location is approximate because the source is not available." That's fine, but I would like to be able to put additional breakpoints into this "virtual file" so that I don't have to step line by line until I get to the line of interest. Placing these breakpoints does not seem to be possible.

I also can't figure out how to edit the file (which would presumably then support breakpoints). Perhaps I need to install the source locally but it is not clear how to do that. Also, I don't know what the implications of using the source code is. Would I need to manually compile any parts of the library that are actually compiled? My preference would be to have an installation option that allows for editing anything that is interpreted but that doesn't force me to compile everything that the standard installation method typically compiles on its own.

Comment: Your post looks like a wall of text. If you format it a bit you'll get more people to read your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
trace(Fun_name, edit = T)
```

Comment: To make it a good answer, please improve your answer with an explanation or citation or both.